# Draggable CSS Toggle Switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS Toggle Switch which I got from somewhere on the web.

It works but is not draggable. When you drag the handle on either side, the knob enlarges but doesn't move in the specified direction. The only way to change the value is to click on the other space. But I need the Drag operation, if sufficiently advanced, to also change the value. After a certain amount of drag the the toggle needs to flip. Is this possible?

```css
/* SWITCH */
.form-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.form-switch i {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  width: 46px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 23px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.form-switch i::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.form-switch i::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
} 

.form-switch:active i::after {
  width: 28px;
  transform: translate3d(2px, 2px, 0);
}

.form-switch:active input:checked + i::after { transform: translate3d(16px, 2px, 0); }

.form-switch input { display: none; }

.form-switch input:checked + i { background-color: #4BD763; }

.form-switch input:checked + i::before { transform: translate3d(18px, 2px, 0) scale3d(0, 0, 0); }

.form-switch input:checked + i::after { transform: translate3d(22px, 2px, 0); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="form-switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <i></i>
  Select Me
</label>
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: No, have not solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You already use JQuery so just set the CSS behavior with `*.draggable*`

```
 $(".victim").draggable({
      //css animation here
 });
```

Also set the *`victim`* class to the `*input*`